# Is there a converse of Abhyankar-Moh-Suzuki theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, fields

The following question is the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838180/is-there-a-converse-of-abhyankar-moh-suzuki-theorem); I ask it here, since I have not got any comments there (I really apologize if I should have waited some more time before asking it here; it is just that recently I have asked there also several related questions without getting any comments).

Let $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in k[t]$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.

The well-known theorem of [Abhyankar-Moh-Suzuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhyankar%E2%80%93Moh_theorem) says the following:
If $k[f,g]=k[t]$, then $\deg(f) | \deg(g)$ or $\deg(g) | \deg (f)$. (Actually, there is a version in any characteristic, but characteristic zero is good enough for me. Moreover, in view of the second remark below, perhaps it is better to assume that $k$ is also algebraically closed).

> Is there some kind of converse, namely, something like: 
>   If $\deg(f) | \deg(g)$ or $\deg(g) | \deg (f)$ and $f$ and $g$ satisfy property $P$, then $k[f,g]=k[t]$?

Of course, property $P$ must include: $k(f,g)=k(t)$, but this alone is not enough, as $(f,g)=(t^6+t^2,t^3)$ shows; indeed, $k(t^6+t^2,t^3)=k(t^2,t^3)=k(t)$ but $k[t^6+t^2,t^3] \subsetneq k[t]$.
Notice that the condition that $\deg(g) | \deg(f)$ is quite 'artificial' since we just added $t^6=(t^3)^2$ to $t^2$, and $\{t^2,t^3\}$ has relatively prime degrees (so by AMS theorem there is no chance that $\{t^2,t^3\}$ will generate $k[t]$)
and $k[t^6+t^2,t^3]=k[t^2,t^3]$.

I had several ideas for property $P$, but unfortunately they did not guarantee that $k[f,g]=k[t]$, for example: If both $f$ and $g$ are odd polynomials = having terms of odd degrees only. Notice that if $f$ and $g$ are just odd polynomials then they can be far from generating $k[t]$, for example, $(f,g)=(t^5,t^{15})$, for which $k(f,g)=k(t^5,t^{15})=k(t^5) \subsetneq k(t)$.
[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825630/does-kf-g-kh-where-f-and-g-are-odd-polynomials-imply-that-h-is-als?rq=1) only shows that if $f$ and $g$ are odd polynomials, then $k(f,g)=k(h)$, where $h$ is a polynomial of odd degree but not necessarily of degree $1$, like here that $h=t^5$ (notice that the existence of such $h$ follows from Luroth-Noether theorem).

But even if we assume that two odd polynomials $f$ and $g$ satisfy $k(f,g)=k(t)$, there is no guarantee that $k[f,g]=k[t]$, as $(f,g)=(t^5,t^{15}+t^3)$ shows; indeed, $k(t^5,t^{15}+t^3)=k(t^5,t^3)=k(t^2,t^3)=k(t)$ but $k[t^5,t^{15}+t^3] \subsetneq k[t]$.

**Remarks:**

**(1)** There are very nice criteria for $k[f,g]=k[t]$ and $k(f,g)=k(t)$, see Theorem 2.1 of [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2161575?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). However, in practice, D-resultant seems not useful; perhaps it is useful only for very low degrees such as $(\deg(f),\deg(g)) \in \{(2,2),(3,3),(2,4)\}$.

**(2)** If $k$ is also algebraically closed (this is necessary!), then: $k[f,g]=k[t]$ if and only if for all $t \in k$, $(f'(t),g'(t))\neq (0,0)$ and $H: t \mapsto (f(t),g(t))$ is injective, see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2839040_Around_the_Abhyankar-Moh_Theorem). However, showing that $H$ is injective is difficult (except low degrees cases).
Based on this result and on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1) we can get: $k[f,g]=k[t]$ if and only if for all $\lambda,\mu \in k$, $\deg(\gcd(f(t)-\lambda,g(t)-\mu)) \leq 1$.
(I can add a proof for this if someone will require. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831002/a-relation-between-common-roots-of-f-and-g-and-common-roots-of-f-lambda-a)).

Any comments are welcome!