# A variation on Abhyankar–Moh–Suzuki theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, fields, resultants

The well-known theorem of [Abhyankar–Moh–Suzuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhyankar%E2%80%93Moh_theorem) says the following:
Let $f=f(t), g=g(t) \in k[t]$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
If $k[f,g]=k[t]$, then $\deg(f) \mid \deg(g)$ or $\deg(g) \mid \deg (f)$.

Let us concentrate on the case $k=\mathbb{C}$ (I wonder if there is a difference in my following question between $k=\mathbb{C}$ and $k=\mathbb{R}$).

Let $f=f(t), g=g(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ satisfy the following conditions:

**(1)** $f=hf_1$, $g=hg_1$, where $\gcd(f_1,g_1)=1$
(= $h$ is the gcd of $f$ and $g$) and each of
$\deg(h)$, $\deg(f_1)$, $\deg(g_1)$ is $\geq 1$.

**(2)** $\deg(f_1)=\deg(g_1)$, hence $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$.

**(3)** $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(t)$.

> Should such $f$ and $g$ generate $\mathbb{C}[t]$, namely, $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t]$?

I have not found an example of such $f$ and $g$ not generating $\mathbb{C}[t]$, but maybe I am missing something easy.

Maybe one (or more) of the following ideas could help:

**(i)** The following known criterion:
$\mathbb{C}[f(t),g(t)]=\mathbb{C}[t]$ iff $(f'(t),g'(t))\neq 0$ and $t\mapsto (f(t),g(t))$ is injective, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733573/why-mathbbcf-1t-f-2t-mathbbct-iff-f-1t-f-2t-neq0-and?noredirect=1&lq=1).

**(ii)** The theory of SAGBI bases (I will try to find relevant papers, I remember there are ones. I think there is a result saying that if $f', g' \in \mathbb{C}[f,g]$, then $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t]$).

**(iii)** The theory of sub-resultants.

(**(iv)** Maybe if $\deg(h)=1$, then I can show that $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t]$. However, I prefer not restricting $\deg(h)$).

Somewhat relevant questions: [Is there a converse of Abhyankar-Moh-Suzuki theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304189/is-there-a-converse-of-abhyankar-moh-suzuki-theorem) and [Generalizations of Abhyankar-Moh theorem (embeddings of the line in the plane)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295158/generalizations-of-abhyankar-moh-theorem-embeddings-of-the-line-in-the-plane).

Any comments are welcome!

**Edit:** I have now found a counterexample for the case $\deg(g) \geq 2$:
$f=t^{15}+t^2$, $g=t^{15}$. Conditions **(1),(2),(3)** are being satisfied, but $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t^2] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[t]$.
So only when $\deg(h)=1$ perhaps there is a positive answer.

Therefore, and in view of idea **(i)**, we will add a fourth condition:

**(4)** $f',g'$ are not simultaneously zero.

Then, the above counterexample is not a counterexample anymore, since $f'=15t^{14}+2t$, $g'=15t^{14}$ have a common zero at $0$.

Comment: Your second question link (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295158/generalizations-of-abhyankar-moh-theorem-embeddings-of-the-line-in-the-plane/295575#295575) goes to an answer.  Was that intentional?

Comment: @LSpice, no, it was not intensional. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: $f=t^{15}+t^2$, $g=t^{15}$ is a counterexample....

Comment: Therefore, and in view of idea (i), we will add the condition that $f',g'$ are not simultaneously zero. Then, the above counterexample is not a counterexample anymore, since $f'=15t^{14}+2t$, $g'=15t^{14}$ have a common zero at $0$.

Comment: If $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=n$ and $\deg(h)=n-1$ (so $\deg(f_1)=\deg(g_1)=1$), then I think it is not difficult to show that $t \mapsto (f(t),g(t))$ is injective, so with new condition (4) we obtain that $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t]$. But for $\deg(h) \geq 2$ and $\deg(f_1)=\deg(g_1) \geq 2$, I do not know how to show that   $t \mapsto (f(t),g(t))$ is injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. You can simply choose $$f=t(t^2-t+1)$$
$$g=t(t^2+1)$$
These satisfy all your conditions, but $\mathbb{C}[f,g]\subsetneq \mathbb{C}[t]$.

Let us check this:

$(1)-(2)$: $f=tf_1$ and $g=tg_1$ where $f_1=t^2-t+1$, $g_1= t^2+1$ are both of degree $2$ and without common factor.

$(3)$: $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(t)$ because $g-f=t^2$, so $\frac{g}{g-f+1}=t$.

Finally, we observe that
$\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[f-g,g]=\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3+1]=\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]\subsetneq \mathbb{C}[t]$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was curious about the case $\deg(h) \geq 2$, which also has a counterexample https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340517/mathbbcf-g-mathbbct-and-ft-gt-neq-0-but-mathbbcf-g/4340537?noredirect=1#comment9055263_4340537 Please, do you think there exists a 'mild' condition (in addition to (1)-(4)) that would imply $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t]$?

Comment: I remember a paper with condition $f',g' \in  \mathbb{C}[f,g]$, but it does not seem 'mild' to me.

Comment: Asking that $f',g'$ do not have a common zero implies to have an immersion. If $t\mapsto (f(t),g(t))$ is moreover injective, then you are done. But maybe this is not enough mild for you?

Comment: Thank you. It is too strong for me to require that $t \mapsto (f(t),g(t)$ is injective.. I wish to consider $f$ and $g$ of degree $\geq 4$ satisfying (1)-(4).

Answer (score 1):

Since you (OP) seem to be interested in Lüroth’s theorem, you might want to look at a ["constructive" proof](https://pinakimondal.org/luroths-theorem-a-constructive-proof/) that I just wrote up from Schinzel's Selected topics on polynomials. It seems using it one can show (see the bottom part of the linked page) that $\mathbb{C}(f,g) = \mathbb{C}(t)$ if $\deg(f)$ and $\deg(g)$ are relatively prime.

I am still a bit skeptical about the result - it seems too good to be true. In any event, if I have not made any mistake and it is indeed true, then this gives a lot of counterexamples to your question, since for any polynomial $h$ with no multiple roots, there are (infinitely many) $f_1, g^*_1$ such that

1. $d := \deg(h) + \deg(f_1)$ and $e^* := \deg(h) + \deg(g^*_1)$ are relatively prime,
2. $d > e^*$,
3. $e^*$ does not divide $d$, and
4. there is no common zero of $(f_1h)'$ and $(g^*_1h)'$.

Then setting $f := f_1h$ and $g := (f_1 + g^*_1)h$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. My condition (2) says that $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$, so the additional condition that $\deg(f)$ and $\deg(g)$ are relatively prime would imply that $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=1$.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{C}(f, g) = \mathbb{C}(f, f+g)$, you can simply substitute $g$ by $f+g$.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you.